# Can I alter the Alert system in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-alerts

Can I alter the Alert system in SharePoint, I want an email sent to different people based on what buttons are selected in a list.

Comment: Please clarify a little- what do you mean by "what buttons are selected in a list"? Are you saying you want something to happen when a list item is created, based on what values they have set for various attributes of that list item?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question as far as I can follow it, is that you can do it by triggering a workflow when list items are created.